# Vim regex - quantifier

Tags: regex, vim

I have a problem with following expression in vim.

In text: `AekwoeuwioeuwioeuwB_AewieuiwuiweuB-A32r3r3hruh3u2huB A32r3r3hruh3u2huB`  I would like to select A-B strings separately. Something which is achievable by `A.*?B` in standard regex. However I am not able to do this in vim.

Comment: _The nice thing about standards is that there are so many to chose from._ -- A. S. Tanenbaum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for the non-greedy "zero or more" match `A.*?B` in Vim is `A.\{-}B`. See `:help /\{-`.

An overview of the main differences to Perl's regular expression dialect can be found at `:help perl-patterns`.

#### Alternative

For simple patterns, the end delimiter can be excluded from the range, so that the default greedy matching will work, too: `A[^B]*B`

Comment: I read  about `\{-}` but was wondering why `A.*\{-}B` did not work:) +1 For alternative.